# 'http" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: windows, windows-10, curl

I am trying to run a `curl` command and getting this error:

```
'http" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

I looked where I have `curl.exe`, found it in `C:\Program Files\GDAL` and deleted it.

The error persisted. This was `curl.exe` in `C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin`, so I deleted it too.

The error still persisted. There was one more `curl.exe` in the `$PATH`.

So error is independent of the executable. How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the output of `curl --version` ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### Ensure you are supplying `curl` with double quotes (`"`), not single quotes (`'`)

Curl in Windows is know to not like single quotes as per (for example) [this thread](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/curl-https-not-supported-or-disabled-in-libcurl/43204):

> ```
> D:\nr\platform_installer_win32>curl -X GET 'http://api.newrelic.com/v2/applications.json' \ -H "X-Api-Key:${APIKEY}" -i
> curl: (1) Protocol "'http" not supported or disabled in libcurl
> ```
>
> (...)
>
> I  believe the first warning you're seeing is due to wrapping the url in **single quotes instead of double**.

(from NewRelic forums, emphasis mine)

This also popped up in a [QA over on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684235/perl-curl-1-protocol-http-not-supported-or-disabled-in-libcurl).